# timestamp_timeout in Ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, sudo, visudo

I use ubuntu 14.04 and I tried to change sudo password timeout but change made to it doesn't work. Please help , My visudo file looks like this.

```
 GNU nano 2.2.6                    File: /etc/sudoers.tmp                                               

 #
 # This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
 #
 # Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
 # directly modifying this file.
 #
 # See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
 #
 Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=15
 Defaults        mail_badpass
 Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:   /usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
 # Host alias specification

 # User alias specification

 # Cmnd alias specification

 # User privilege specification
 root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
 %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old question for an old Ubuntu version, this fixed it for me:

Define `timestamp_type=tty` as well.

```
Defaults        timestamp_timeout=600,timestamp_type=tty
```

Note: when editing this file, make sure you run visudo and not edit the file directly. `sudo visudo` will open the editor on `/etc/sudoers`, and let you save. If any syntax errors are found, it will ask you if you want to fix it or revert to the original, but won't let you save any invalid syntax.

If you modify `/etc/sudoers` manually and mess it up, you'll be left with no sudo privileges and would have to fix it by booting into recovery, dropping to shell and modifying it back.

[Reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/8rxr42/manjaro_17110_sudo_timestamp_timeout_doesnt_work/)